# WindowInstance WPF Custom Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml

Iam trying to create a **custom Window** which will contain some custom Properties. When I run the Application all things go fine but the problem that the xaml designer never recognize these properties

Also the Window's **OnApplyTemplate** method not working under designer

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type windows:MDWindow}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type windows:MDWindow}">

                <Grid >
               <!--This Never Changed At Design Time-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The designers are not always the most reliable tools.  Does it work at run time?

Comment: yes it worked fine at run time but i think about if your window contain a control inside it and the control property bounded to the window so you cannot see the changes on the control until you run the application